Comic about twin Earth at other side of the Sun inhabited by robots
In the 90s, I found an old comic in a public library. I remember the story and graphic style were similar to Spirou and Fantasio from Franquin, but I was not able to find it in the Spirou comics, so it seems to be by another author. The book was old, so it probably was at least of the same era (circa 70s or early 80s, maybe 60s), and based on the story and graphic style, more than probably of French/Belgian origin too. I remember it being called something like "The Planet of Robots", but I was not able to find anything by that title.
The story of this comic seemed to be a non-direct continuation of another previous one, where events (and publication) happened after some years of the first one, probably with some albums published between them. The fragments I remember more or less in order are:

setting was contemporary (second half of XX century)
there are several robots stealing/fetching things and technology on Earth and bringing them to a hidden hanger, and the Spirou-like protagonist and his friends investigating (maybe there's some Secotine-like girl between them?)
robots building a spaceship in the hanger, and found there the inventor building it. The inventor is a 40-ish years old happy fat guy bald and with a big nose. It seems it was already an old friend of the protagonists that was building the spaceship in secret. The robots fetching the material are also of his invention. He wants to go back to a twin-Earth planet hidden at the other side of the Sun, repeating a previous travel, probably done in the previous comic
after finishing the spaceship, all of them travel to the twin-Earth. Travel seems to be almost instantaneous (not teleport or FTL, maybe some minutes/hours). During travel, the inventor reveal that he's in fact a robot clone of the real inventor (by opening his face and showing circuit boards under it), that got strangled in the twin-Earth, and previous to the travel of the first comic (?), he build it as a security measurement, so the robot clone could build the spaceship and go to rescue him
twin-Earth is jungle-like, with some high-edge technology cities inhabited only by robots. It doesn't seem to be there any organic intelligent life form, only the robots imperialist civilization
they find and rescue the inventor, and the robot clone gets deactivated by design because it's close to the inventor and has done his purpose of finding him. There's a celebration, maybe with some local natives, where the inventor gets drunk and falls asleep close to his robot clone. Protagonists got amazed how much alike they are, and with the inventor asleep and the robot clone deactivated, they can't differentiate them
they go back to the spaceship with the asleep inventor, leaving the robot clone to direct the other robots of the planet, and go back to the Earth, and mid travel the profesor starts to wake up just to reveal it's the robot clone that got reactivated

One particular scene I remember but not sure if directly related to the main story, when the protagonists arrive to the robot city, a Fantasio-like protagonist find a factory of some mysterious cubes, that after running over a conveyor belt, they end up in an incinerator and burned to generate energy... for the cubes-producer machine itself, in a short of continuous movement Goldberg machine, and the Fantasio-like protagonist gets hysterical trying to understand what's the machine purpose beyond itself.
Clarifications from the comments:

Full color, size about 30x40cm, and about 48-60 pages. Maybe also editorial Dargaud or similar?
the inventor had some resemblance to Dr. Ochanomizu from Astro Boy, but stories are totally unrelated, resemblance is more about the topic of good-hearted Absent-minded professor


Some parts of this remind me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_murailles_de_Samaris

On second hand, that doesn't match the art style...

It's not the same story style either, it was more adventures/humor, Les murailles de Samaris looks targeting adults. Anyway, it looks interesting, thanks for the reference :-)

The big-nosed inventor and robots makes me also think of Osamu Tezuka (famous for Astro Boy), but I don't see any matching stories.

No, it was not a manga either, it was full size (about DIN A-4) and full color. But yes, the bit-nosed inventor had some resemblance to Astro Boy one :-)
